# Not able to use global variable inside a class - SystemStackError: stack level too deep RUBY

Tags: ruby

My Code

```
def property_values_list
  property_values = {"ceremonial"=>249, "party"=>250, "wedding"=>251, "casual"=>252} 
end

$property_values = property_values_list()

class Design
  attr_reader  :occasion_ids

  def occasion_ids=(property_name)
    self.occasion_ids = []
    self.occasion_ids << $property_values[property_name]
  end
end

d = Design.new
d.occasion_ids = 'party'
```

Error

SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!

Comment: Remove recursion from `occasio_ids=` method and try to avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a bug, it is just a infinite recursion, because you do a call to assign method `occasion_ids=` from the method itself:

```
def occasion_ids=(property_name)
   self.occasion_ids = []
```

Do assigning to an instance variable:

```
def occasion_ids=(property_name)
   @occasion_ids = []
```

Comment: Thanks. will accepts answer after 10 min. stackoverflow rules